# Angular 5 Material - Dynamically change toolbar name when I change routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-routing

I'm trying to change the material toolbar name dynamically when i switch between pages on sidenav.

```
App-component.html
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-wrap" >
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list (click)="sidenav.close()">
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/']" > Home</a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/products']"> Products</a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/orders']"> Orders</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header role="banner">
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button
          (click)="sidenav.open()"
          title="Menu">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span  class="toolbar_name">Products</span>
      </mat-toolbar>
    </header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: what do you want it to switch between?

Comment: if i press 'my products' menu in sidenav, toolbar name should change accordingly to My Products

Comment: you're going to need to clarify your question with a better example, also the side nav does not open in your example code

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you could change this line to a variable:

```
<span  class="toolbar_name">{{productsVar}}</span>
```

Then in this area use a function instead:

```
<a mat-list-item (click)="navigate('Products')" Products</a>
```

Then in your component class have the function:

```
navigate(area: string) {
     this.productsVar = area;
     this.router.navigate([`/${area}`]);
}
```

Make sure to import "Router" from Angular and inject it into your component class such as:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
```

This way you can use the routing function in your class.  If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Only when i press a menu toolbar name appears and get changed. And i cannot set custom toolbar name like My Products or My orders

Comment: You could pass 'My Products' into the function also.  If that's not what you mean then I will need some example code so I can give you better information.

Comment: I modified this line to =>   <a mat-list-item (click)="navigate('Home','/')"  > Home</a>
        <a mat-list-item (click)="navigate('Products','/products')"  > Products</a>
        <a mat-list-item (click)="navigate('Orders', '/orders')"  > Orders</a>

Comment: If you are using the navigation function I provided, you need to pass a single string. If not, if you could post that function and your routing code is needed to understand where the issue is happening also